# I can not connect to mysql on Oracles ubuntu vps, from mysql workbench or powershell

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, vps

So i have a oracle vps instance with laravel. I have tested it to be working with mysql secure installation. I mean i open the app in browser, make crud operations, etc, everything works. But when i try to connect to that mysql remotely, from my laptop, like from mysql workbench, or windows power shell, or even from my dual boots ubuntus terminal, i always get timeout 10060 error.

So far i have tried E.V.E.R.Y.T.H.I.N.G that google and chatGpt have advised me.

1. I have maid mysql secure install.
2. Created new user for remote access: CREATE USER 'vps'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
3. Granted all privileges: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'vps'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
4. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
5. sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. I tried to comment bind-address line, tried to make it 0.0.0.0, tried to make it my instances ip address.
6. sudo service mysql restart
7. Enabled port 3306 to on ufw and iptables.
8. Triple checked that those are enabled.
9. Disabled ufw and iptables completely. Double... no triple checked that those are not running.
10. Added ingress rules "Tcp, 0.0.0.0/0, 3306" and then "Tcp, 0.0.0.0/0, 33060"
11. Added ingress rules for ping. Ping at least worked.
12. If i try to connect with say powershell i do: "mysql -h 'my-vps-public-ip' -P 3306 -u vps -p" and get ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my-vps-public-ip' (10060)
13. Restarted instance multiple times. Completely deleted mysql server with cleanup, reinstalled. Everything 3 times.

Here is output of netstat -tlnp
ubuntu@test:~$ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3993/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      838/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      734/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33060           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3993/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      893/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      838/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      893/apache2

[Netstat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlOwC.png)

[Ingress rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhiTD.png)

Comment: `ping` uses a different port, thus a working ping does not mean so much. Which port is used by MySQL? 3306 or 33060 or 3600 - maybe first start with this basic information.

Comment: Did you check the network firewall?

Comment: mysql uses 3306 port, That was just a typo in question. Also there is mysqld process that uses 33060 port. I will add output to my question

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> 10. Added ingress rules "Tcp, 0.0.0.0/0, 3306" and then "Tcp,
>     0.0.0.0/0, 33060

That means that you added an ingress rule for TCP with the source ip (0.0.0.0/0) on **source port** 3306

You are suppose to put 3306 on the destination port and leave source port on All, then it becomes

> ingress rule "Tcp, 0.0.0.0/0, All, 3306"

That's the only thing I could find within your text that I could find as a problem

Comment: Thats exactly how i made those. I will try to add image of ingress table if stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to your mysql server from within the actual server before connecting from remote? and have you checked /var/logs/mysql to see if there is any relevant information there? is there any other port which works remotely such as 80?

Comment: I'm afraid i dont understand your first and last question. With ssh i am able to connect to mysql and make queries. And i have been looking in logs with sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log and here are the last lines. Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '0.0.0.0' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).